# How do I make my computer accept output like a printer?

Tags: printing

I have a piece of equipment from the late 1980s. It outputs text and graphics directly to dot matrix and Laserjet III printers. These are starting to be harder to find. I would like to implement a solution which allows me to connect to the computer and "print" to it (a piece of software) then print it to a modern printer or .pdf file. I can't locate the piece of software that would accept the input of the device and emulate an old printer. Any solutions??? Thanks for any help. I know this isn't exactly what most of you do, but I'm hoping someone has had need of something similar in their experience.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Those devices will share a common input language (best bet is to look for the Laserjet II specs). If you don't want to buy the product idealmachine links to you'll want to find out what that language is called and google around for either libraries that parse it (not just emit it mind you, but accept it as input) or a detailed description so that you can figure out how to accept it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It already exists. It's called [PrintCapture](http://www.printcapture.com/) and sells for US$97.00. You will need the necessary interface hardware as well, depending on which type of printer port the device has; they list some of those devices on their web site under the "Details" section.